# Back button to show previous ul with jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I made a questionnaire to help people where should they go when they have a certain type of ticket. Right now I'm having trouble with make the "Back" button to show the previous "ul" or screen that the user seen. At first I'm going to remove the 'active' class of the current "ul" but it won't work. Could show me how to make the back button ?
Thanks
`HTML`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="js.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <section class="question_wrapper">

      <ul class="tab active">
        <li class="active">
          <p>Do you have a ticket ?</p>
          <a href="#tab1">yes</a>
          <a href="#tab2">no</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="tab" id="tab1">
        <li>
          <p>Which Ticket do you have ?</p>
          <a href="#tab3">Type 1</a>
          <a href="#tab3">Type 2</a>
          <a href="#tab3">Type 3</a>
          <a href="#tab4">Type 4</a>
          <a href="#tab4">Type 5</a>
          <a href="#tab5">Type 6</a>
          <button type="button">Back</button>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="tab" id="tab2">
        <li>
          <p>Go buy some ticket then</p>
          <button>Back</button>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="tab" id="tab3">
        <li>
          <p>Please go to hall A</p>
          <button>Back</button>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="tab" id="tab4">
        <li>
          <p>Please go to hall B</p>
          <button>Back</button>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="tab" id="tab4">
        <li>
          <p>Please go to hall C</p>
          <button>Back</button>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </section>

  </body>
</html>
```

`CSS`

```
.question_wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 0;
  width: 40rem;
  height: 20rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.tab {
  display: none;
}
.tab.active {
  display: flex;
}
```

`JS/JQuery`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(function() {
    $(".tab a").click(function() {
      $(this).parent().addClass("active").siblings(".active").removeClass("active");
      var tabContents = $(this).attr("href");
      $(tabContents).addClass("active").siblings(".active").removeClass("active");
      return false;
    });
  });

  $(":button").on("click", function(){
    $(this).parent().removeClass("active");
  });

});
```

Comment: Hi, just out of curiosity, is there a reason for having each 'page' as a ul - the contents don't seem to be a set of li elements, always just one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made a few changes to the button click.

- $(':button') to $('button')
- On click, remove active classname from all ul except the first ul

There is a mistake I found in your code that I found, which is you are using only one `li` in each `ul`, but for each items under ul, you should be using a `li` and if you need more elements, you can use them.

**Update**

Updated the snippet with the functionality to go back to previous `ul` instead of the first one.

I am keeping an additional attribute with each `ul` to identify the level they are in, so when I click on the back button, I am identifying the currentLevel and finding the next one using the currentLevel.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(function() {
    $(".tab a").click(function() {
      $(this).parent().addClass("active").siblings(".active").removeClass("active");
      var tabContents = $(this).attr("href");
      $(tabContents).addClass("active").siblings(".active").removeClass("active");
      return false;
    });
  });

  $("button").on("click", function(){
    let currentLevel = $(this).closest('.tab').attr('data-level');
    let prevLevel = parseInt(currentLevel) - 1;
    $('.tab').removeClass("active");
    $('.tab').each(function(index, item) {
      if(parseInt($(item).attr('data-level')) === prevLevel) {
        $(item).addClass('active');
      }
    })
  });
});
```

```css
.question_wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 0;
  width: 40rem;
  height: 20rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.tab {
  display: none;
}
.tab.active {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="question_wrapper">

      <ul class="tab main-tab active" data-level='1'>
        <li class="active">
          <p>Do you have a ticket ?</p>
          <a href="#tab1">yes</a>
          <a href="#tab2">no</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="tab" data-level='2' id="tab1">
        <li>
          <p>Which Ticket do you have ?</p>
          <a href="#tab3">Type 1</a>
          <a href="#tab3">Type 2</a>
          <a href="#tab3">Type 3</a>
          <a href="#tab4">Type 4</a>
          <a href="#tab4">Type 5</a>
          <a href="#tab5">Type 6</a>
          <button type="button">Back</button>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="tab" id="tab2" data-level='3'>
        <li>
          <p>Go buy some ticket then</p>
          <button>Back</button>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="tab" id="tab3" data-level='3'>
        <li>
          <p>Please go to hall A</p>
          <button>Back</button>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="tab" id="tab4" data-level='3'>
        <li>
          <p>Please go to hall B</p>
          <button>Back</button>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="tab" id="tab5" data-level='3'>
        <li>
          <p>Please go to hall C</p>
          <button>Back</button>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </section>
```

Comment: You should explain what changes you've made.

Comment: Yeah sure @Andy, I was editing the answer after posting it. Just added the mistakes and something additional which has no direct link to the current issue

Comment: @AbinThaha Thanks a lot man. But if I want the "Back" button to go the previous ul and not the first ul, how can I made the adjustment ?

Comment: Sure, that can be done @Kenken, but you need to restructure your elements in such a way, or you need to add additional params along with the `ul`. I will update the above snippet with the second method

Comment: @Kenken, I have updated the snippet with the desired functionality, can you check and confirm

Comment: @AbinThaha Thank a lot man ! This is what I'm looking for. So you add an additional to each 'ul' with 'data-level'. I've never use data-level before, what is it for ?

Comment: data-level is a custom attribute. user defined attribute. You can call it any name. @Kenken, if this works for your requirement, kindly accept the answer.

Comment: @AbinThaha Ow ! I see, thanks for the explanation !. I have accpet the answer.
Thank you so much.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234144/discussion-between-kenken-and-abin-thaha).